# Home address for uk visa application documents if living with husband?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I am married to an EU citizen, I am confused about what to submit on "home address" supporting documents. I don't have a mortgage or property deed simply because I live with my husband. So what should I fill with the missing supporting documents of home address if I am currently living with my husband?

Comment: Where does it say that supporting documents of home address are required? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: Its actually on checklist.after paying the visa fee

Comment: Sort of like supporting documents

Comment: The checklist is a guide, it’s not expected that you should submit evidence for everything on it. Having said that, presumably other evidence you’ll be supplying such as bank statements, employment contract etc should show your address?

Comment: Yea thats what i am hoping they will consider..cant provide any of the following such as deed of sale since i dont own any property and just currently living with my husband.So imaybe i could satisfy them by providing evidence of my husbands existence..showing both address on our documents..

Answer (score 1):

When making a UK visitor visa application, the main thing that you have to demonstrate is that you will return home after your trip. This is why you have been asked to give evidence that you have somewhere to live outside the UK when you apply. Someone who has no home is much more likely to try and stay in the UK beyond the limit of their visa. As Traveller pointed out in the comments, remember that the checklist is just a guide and doesn't cover every possible situation. When the checklist asks for a tenancy or mortgage agreement, they are asking for evidence you have somewhere to live (and therefore a reason to leave the UK at the end of your trip), not that you must provide these specific documents.

Since you live with your husband and he owns the home you live in, this puts you in a very good position with regards to evidence that you have somewhere to live. Supplying proof that your husband owns his home will be very strong evidence, and you should certainly submit it with your visa, along with evidence of your relationship to your husband such as your marriage certificate. Note that if the deeds aren't in English, you'll need a certified translation, as with any other documents you submit that aren't in English.

As an aside, 1st November may not be the best date to travel to the UK, as this is currently set to be the first day after the UK will have left the EU, and it's possible there may be travel disruption.

Comment: Thats a very helpful information but i am not really in control of the trip..my husband will take his chaces anyway..we will submit the documents needed and might pursue november 1 to watch a concert.thank you for the help

Comment: Do i need EEA family permit?or its best to apply visit visa

Comment: If you were travelling before brexit, the EEA family permit would be the best option. The date of brexit is up in the air but at the moment it looks like you’ll be travelling after. Therefore the safe option is to apply for a visit visa.

Comment: Thats what my husband said  is to apply for visit visa..onstead of EEA permit..we are travelling tje 1st day of brexit.